# Pass data to the same page in express

Tags: node.js, express, post, routes, pug

i want to pass data from server to the same page if there is an error in the POSTED data.

i have two routes , one route to display the contents and the other route for adding new content. i am using pug as view.

form for the new content is :

```
extends layout

block content
  form(action="/create", method="POST") 
    h2= title 
    p 
    | Text :
        input(type="text", name="text")
    input(type="submit")
```

whenever i click the submit button the value in the input is posted

here's the node `route.post()` code :

```
router.post('/create' ,function(req,res,next){
  if(req.body.text === ''){
    res.send("empty")
  }else{
    contents.push(text: req.body.text )
    res.redirect('/')
  }
} )
```

currently if i submit the form without any input value , it will send "empty" msg in a blank page.
What I want is that if the input value is empty, rather than sending "empty" in a blank page i want to send "empty" msg to the same `Form` page and show anywhere.
like this :

[image]

thank you : ) ......

Comment: Are you parsing Request object: `app.use(express.json())` ?

Answer (score 0):

We must use a variable to indicate there is an error. For example:

View

```
extends layout

block content
  form(action="/create", method="POST") 
    h2= title 
    p 
    | Text :
        input(type="text", name="text")
    input(type="submit")
    h2= error
```

Controller

```
router.post('/create' ,function(req,res,next){
  if(req.body.text === ''){
    res.render("your_view_name_here", { error: "empty" })
  }else{
    contents.push(text: req.body.text )
    res.redirect('/')
  }
})
```